# Can Fancybox be responsive only horizontally for tall content?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a site with some very tall images. I'd like for these images to respond in a responsive way horizontally, but not vertically. If they conform to the height of the browser, they become too small to see properly.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this that I'm missing?

See an example below. Click on the second thumbnail "bswift", then a small grey square to launch Fancybox.
http://www.eaaronrossdesign.com/index2.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try combining the `fitToView` and `maxWidth` API options like :

```
$('.thumbs_small').fancybox({
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    fitToView: false, // images won't be scaled to fit to browser's height
    maxWidth: "90%" // images won't exceed the browser's width
});
```

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4jyr/)**

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks! I kept only using one or the other.

Comment: it doesn't work if i set maxWidth with pixels... any idea why?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino : Once again you make comments out of context. First you down-vote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272517/how-can-i-make-fancybox-2-adjust-its-height-to-fit-its-contents/16273620#comment52286102_16273620) because the `width` is not "fluid" and then you wonder why it doesn't work if you set the `width` in pixels. Setting fixed widths (in pixels) won't ever give you a "fluid" width. You may want to read http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design if you have any doubt ;)

Comment: @MattiaNocerino : just notice that if you set `maxWidth` in pixels, only be tangible if the viewport is wider than the value you set.

Comment: So, the only way to have a fluid width and a "content-based height" is to set a % maxWidth. To me, it doesn't make sense

Comment: By the way these comments where not out of the context. In the other question i went mad, sorry