# Adobe Edge animation in fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, adobe-edge

I'm trying to integrate an Adobe Edge animation in a Fancybox iframe. It works so far... **BUT** on scaling the viewport down a white border on the bottom appears.

(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13655174/Screenshot%20-%2026.11.2013%20%2C%2021_06_52.png)

I know this problem is an effect of calling the whole Edge HTML-Page, i just dont know how to fix this issue.

I used this script in Adobe Edge:

http://sarahjustine.com/2013/04/08/create-scale-to-fit-projects-with-adobe-edge-animate/

Thats my code:

jQuery:

```
        $(".fancybox_iframe").fancybox({
             type: 'iframe',
             'width' : '960px',
             'height' : '731px',
             scrolling: 'no',
             fitToView: true,
             iframe: {
             scrolling: 'no',
             preload: false,                
             },
             padding : 0,
             margin : 40,
             nextEffect : 'none',
             prevEffect : 'none',
             openEffect : 'fade',
             autoCenter : true
             });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <a class="fancybox_iframe"  alt="" rel="gallery" href="sevenm.html">
                <div id="sevenm"><img src="img/works/thumbs/thumb_sevenm.jpg" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
                </div> </a>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you need to set `fitToView` to `false`. BTW, for `width` and `height` you just need to set the integer value (without quotes and without `px`) like `width: 960`

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

The border does not appear anymore... But now the fancybox isnt responsive. Its cut off on the right and the bottom.

Comment: then don't set fixed dimensions but % check this if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245491/1055987