# Fancybox height issue @print

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Am using fancy box 2.1.5.

When I want to print the content from the fancy box, this only limited to the html/body height. Have tried overflow visible. But its definitely the height issue. When I set the height of the html/body @print to let say 9999px then all content is showed but have of course loads of empty pages to print.

How can I reset the height (think fancy box set the height to 100% of window) to be the same height as the fancy-content height when printing?

Any solution to this matteR?
Thank you for your time

```
<div id="fancy-content">here is the long text content</div>
```

calling the fancy-content to show

```
<a href="#fancy-content" class="showContent">Fancy Content</a>

$(".showContent").fancybox( { 'padding': 40, 'showCloseButton': true });
```

Comment: Could you provide an online demo?

Comment: try setting `fitToView:false` and `maxWidth: "90%"` (or so), check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245491/1055987 for reference