# Fancybox 2 w. Rails 4 - Can't Make Width Responsive on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

Using Fancybox 2 in Rails 4. Can't adjust any Fancybox properties by calling $.fancybox(..) from landing.js, as I'm supposed to be able to. Fancybox instructions / most StackOverflow threads just suggest:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   padding: 0,
   width : 1000,
   margin : 0
});
```

Or something of the sort. Also seen just $.fancybox({}) a lot. When those wouldn't work for me, I ultimately just decided to use the CSS on #sign_up_form_2 div and avoid having to adjust the Fancybox properties directly. However, on mobile, the box is way too thin and squished. When I try to update the minWidth - its styled shape (w/ background and border - all squished and thin as I see it now - stays the exact same and the extra width is just blank white space). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

landing.html.haml

```
.container
.row
  .col-md-12
    #sign_up_form_2.fancybox
      %h3#new_user Sign Up For The Beta
      = form_for @beta_signup, :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'data-parsley-errors-container="#sign_up_form_2 col-md-8"' ,:id => 'beta_form'}, url: {action: "create", controller: "beta_signup"} do |f|
        .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
          = f.text_field :name, data: {parsley_required: true}, :placeholder => "Full Name", :class => "input"

        .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
          = f.email_field :email, data: {parsley_required: true}, type: 'email', :placeholder => "Email Address", :class => "input"

        .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
          = f.select :gender, options_for_select([['', ''],['Male', 'male'],['Female', 'female']])

        .form-group.col-md-6.col-xs-12
          = f.text_field :zip, data: {parsley_required: true}, type:'number', :placeholder => "Zip Code", :class => "input"

        = f.submit "SIGN UP", :class => 'form_sign_up_button col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-12'
```

landing.css.scss

```
#sign_up_form_2 {
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgb(232,232,232);
    border:20px solid rgba(240,49,49,.4);
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed, Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 50vh;

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
     height: 70vh;
    }
    @media (max-width: 400px) {
     width: 250px;
     height: 85vh;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 10px solid rgba(240,49,49,.4);
    }
  }
```

landing.js

```
var form = $('#sign_up_form_2');
 $('.form_link').on('click', function(){
    $('#sign_up_form_2').show();
    $.fancybox(form);
 });
```

Comment: You can either use `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` to bind fancybox to a selector (and launch fancybox after a `click`) or use `$.fancybox()` to launch fancybox programmatically. Regarding responsiveness check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245491/1055987 if that helps