# Fancybox responsive horizontally but not vertically. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have some sample code up at http://defyordie.com/testbed/
This is for my portfolio and I'm working on replacing my old plugin with fancybox. My issue is with the responsiveness of the work sample popups. Scroll down to my 'work' section and click on one of the top 3 boxes since those are finished.
I'm working on a big cinema display, so I've noticed that as i expand my window, the royalslider running the slideshow expands horizontally but doesnt expand vertically until i make the browser window almost entirely fill my screen. I had hoped that it would scale proportionally. I've either initalized the fancybox incorrectly, royalslider incorrectly, or I have some sort of CSS issue.

The code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            $(window).on({
                'resize.fancybox': function () {
                    $.fancybox.update();
                }
            });
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $(window).off('resize.fancybox');
        },
        padding: 0,
        margin: [60, 15, 0, 15],
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            $.extend(this, {
                type: 'html',
                width: '95%',
                height: '100%',
                minWidth: '930px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244157/can-fancybox-be-responsive-only-horizontally-for-tall-content, https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/550

Comment: thanks for the quick response Sigma! I'm not sure the first thread applies to me. I DO want my content to scale vertically as well as horizontally. The 2nd issue may apply to me but using their code doesnt appear to fix my issue. Id post my code here if I could fit it.From what i can guestimate, my fancybox doesnt begin to scale vertically til my window is roughly 1780px wide