# How to control the size of captions in jquery fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

### Problem

We're using jquery fancybox to pull images and captions from instagram.

This works well until the plugin tries to render a long caption on mobile. Then the plugin makes the image very thin (see attached), making the caption even longer.

We can see that the size is being applied from the plugin directly onto the element so assume it's the JS.

[image: caption too thin]

### Question

Is there a way to stop the plugin from doing this? All the other settings work great.

We've played with the auto sizing settings but mustn't be using the right combination. With `autoSize : false,` set the plugin still resizes in this weird way.

Happy if the user has to scroll.

### Setup

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('.instagram-gallery')[0]) {

        $(".instagram-gallery .fancybox-gallery-item")
        .attr('rel', 'instagram-gallery-trigger')
        .fancybox({
            padding    : 0,
            margin     : 0,
            nextEffect : 'elastic',
            prevEffect : 'elastic',
            autoCenter : false,
            tpl: {
                closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="#"></a>',
                next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="#"><span></span></a>',
                prev: '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="#"><span></span></a>'
            },

            // this adds the caption from the 'alt' attribute
            beforeShow : function() {
                var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
                this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
                this.title = alt;
            }
        });
    };
}); // document.ready
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You most like need this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245491/1055987

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/1ejyqbfd/ the first image shows the issue and the second the fix