# Fancybox: 100% width -100px

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I'm currently trying to find a way to display FancyBox over the whole width of my screen with a 100px margin on the left. I tried this

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     'width': '100%'         
 });
});
```

and **CSS**

```
.fancybox-wrap {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
}
```

Ok, this works fine, but now i have a horizontal scrollbar in my browser that is caused by the 100 percent + 100px width.

What I'm wondering now, is there a way to get the 100 percent browser width minus 100px?
I tried this, but it didn't work:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   'width': (100% - 100) + "px"      
   });
});
```

Would be great if anyone could provide some working lines of code, I totally suck at coding. TY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without editing any css, fancybox provides you the options

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width: "100%",
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 100] // top, right, bottom, left
});
```

Comment: ... the most comfortable solution.

Comment: @Ela : what exactly : the margin or the width?

Comment: I discovered that in fancybox 2.0 you need to also add "autoSize: false" for the width to work. Even then the popup doesn't take the whole space and leaves about 20px margin.

Comment: @Ela this answer works within the context of the OP, but it may vary from case to case .... you may also need set `fitToView` to `false` to handle the fancybox dimensions on your own. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/16273620/1055987 for more

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the underling HTML for this fancybox, but if you set CSS `right` property to zero, `width` to `auto` and `left` to `100px` you should get it.

Comment: Looks promising, will test it and report.. Edit: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!